# Remove item from xml list with Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have the following xml file:

```
<ArrayOfNO xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <No>
    <Id>0</Id>
    <Name>txt_0</Name>
    <Texto>Função 0</Texto>
    <Txt_relacionados>
       <string>txt_1</string>
       <string>txt_2</string>
    </Txt_relacionados>
    <Nível>2</Nível>
    <X>393</X>
    <Y>55</Y>
</No>
<No>
    <Id>0</Id>
    <Name>txt_1</Name>
    <Texto>Função 0</Texto>
    <Txt_relacionados>
       <string>txt_0</string>
    </Txt_relacionados>
    <Nível>1</Nível>
    <X>234</X>
    <Y>115</Y>
</No>
<No>
  <Id>1</Id>
  <Name>txt_2</Name>
  <Texto>Função 1</Texto>
  <Txt_relacionados>
    <string>txt_0</string>
  </Txt_relacionados>
  <Nível>1</Nível>
  <X>234</X>
  <Y>115</Y>
</No>
</ArrayOfNO>
```

I wish that when the element is removed (`"txt2"` for example), the program seeks in the `<Txt_relacionados>` of all elements to check if any item related to the `"txt_2"`, and if true remove.

I have deleted the item with the code below (It is working):

```
public void remove(String name)
    {
        RefreshXDoc();
        var oEmp = doc.Descendants().Elements("No")
            .Where(d => d.Element("Name").Value == name)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        if (oEmp == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        oEmp.Remove();
        SaveXDoc();
    }
```

But first need to remove all items from the list "txt_relacionados" the other elements that are related to it (do not know how to implement). I tried something like this:

```
var oEmp = doc.Descendants("No").Elements("Txt_relacionados")
            .Where(d => d.Element("string").Value == name)
            .ToList();
        oEmp.Remove();

        SaveXDoc();
```

Anyone have suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: You need a recursive algorithm since each node may reference other nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this way to remove all `<string>` elements within `<Txt_relacionados>` having value equals `name` :

```
doc.Descendants("No")
    .Elements("Txt_relacionados")
    .Elements("string")
    .Where(s => (string)s == name)
    .Remove();

SaveXDoc();
```

No need for `ToList()` here, you can just call extension method `.Remove()` directly since that method [defined for `IEnumerable<XNode>` source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357554%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

First remove node from xml structure then save new xml structure:

```
foreach (var node in oEmp)
{
    node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(oEmp);                
}
SaveXDoc();
```